# PHP blog (iterating through array data)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not especially experienced in PHP, but I've been trying to create a basic blog for a friend's website. I thought the easiest thing to do for now would be to use static files, so I'm using XML to store the blog entries. I've managed to set it up perfectly in that I can display the posts as I want them. However, I now want a nav bar which will allow me to select posts based on date, as most blogs have. The files are simply named 1.xml, 2.xml, 3.xml etc. so I can iterate through them. Here's the code that shows how the data array is organised (it's an array within an array so that the first level will be equivalent to the number in the filename +1). So I'm having a lot of trouble working out how I can create the nav bar (ul, li etc.) from this data. Presumably I'd need years to be unique and then the months in the years to be unique and also with the days, then I can have each title (obviously a link) come under the proper date.

```
$data = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfPosts; $i++) {
    $filename = './blogentries/' . $i . '.xml';
    if (!file_exists($filename))
        throw new Exception();

    $blogentry = simplexml_load_file($filename);

    $title = $blogentry->title;
    $dateD = $blogentry->date->day;
    $dateM = $blogentry->date->month;
    $dateY = $blogentry->date->year;
    if (strlen($dateY) === 2) $dateY = '20' . $dateY;
    $entryParagraphs = $blogentry->entry->children();

    $data[] = array(
            (string)$title,
            array(
                (string)$dateY,
                (string)$dateM,
                (string)$dateD
            ),
            $entryParagraphs
        );
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give. And sorry if I've not been as eloquent as I might have been, I hope you'll forgive my relative ignorance!

Comment: `I'm not especially experienced in PHP, but I've been trying to create a basic blog for a friend's website.` **Use wordpress**

Comment: why you are using xml you can mysql or nay rdbms

Comment: @hek2mgl Good point, but I really would like to learn how to make this for my own sake too. I realize that I might have made a mess thus far (or maybe I haven't?), but if anyone can give me any pointers on how I can sort this out, it's much appreciated!

Comment: Do you do that to have a good result or to teach yourself? If you want to do a serious thing, you should learn object oriented PHP and consider having a database or as @hek2mgl suggested don't reinvent the wheel. Otherwise it could be a good project (learning the two things I first mentionned could be good even in that case). Otherwise, what is your problem with the navbar especially? Because I don't understand what you are missing for what you ask.

Comment: It is no problem that you make your own blog software. But please do not put it online without having a pro check the whole code for security issues.

Comment: @Lefèvre Again, if it is really your friend create a wordpress blog for him. ;)

Comment: @MisterJ Thanks for the advice. I do understand the basics of OOP, but thought the code for this would be so small that it seemed easiest to me just to do it imperatively. As for the problem with the nav bar, I have the dates for each post stored in the array, but on the bar if a post has the same year as another, I obviously only want the year to be shown once and both posts to be under that. I can do that part, but when it comes to getting the months and days under the years (and then the title under the day), I can't. I'd have the same problem even if the data were stored in a database?

Comment: A database is not actually needed for a blog: a YAML + Markdown combination is way enough [see all the Jekyll-oriented stuff around].

Comment: @moonwave99 may not be needed, but the author seems to think it will be harder to do it with a database, while in my opinion is not true. I'm pretty sure Jekyll-oriented stuff as you said haven't made their choices because of complexity, but for better reasons.

Comment: @MisterJ Actually, when I said harder, I meant simply that I'd need my friend to set up MySQL and get the details from them, so harder in that sense, not necessarily technically harder. :)

Comment: Yeah instead of databases it uses content placed in a directory structure. Fair enough I guess but yikes

Comment: Sorry, my mistake then, I think you were thinking "Hum, new thing, it will be hard to learn and will not get me where I want" which is comprehensive but often wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, I will go with this type of solution : 
First of all, if you do know a little bit of OOP, please create an Article class.

After that, here is what I would do for what you are asking :
Instead of creating an array (which should in fact be a class, (the first array, I don't know if you do realize that), I would do this array :

```
$data[$dateY][$dateM][$dateD]=$blogentry;
```

Then, you have all your articles classified by Year, then month, then day, so it becomes really simple to end with your request.

edit : 
When I said it should be a class, I'm talking about this array :

```
array(
        (string)$title,
        array(
            (string)$dateY,
            (string)$dateM,
            (string)$dateD
        ),
        $entryParagraphs
    )
```

It's typically what a class is designed for.

Comment: From what I understood, your problem was "How can I have my articles categorized by year, then by month, then by day" which is the solution I wrote. Seems like I misunderstood, can you be more precise about what you want then?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote then before you elaborated on your answer. :) I'll have to see if this works and get back to you.

Comment: All I get is this error message: Illegal offset type in C:\wamp\www\blog\index2.php on line 49

Comment: Given the fact I do not have all your data structure, maybe, in the best case where you will do an Article class, there is two solutions. First one, you only need small thing about the article (like you are only going to provide a link, with no more information) then you should go with `$data[$dateY][$dateM][$dateD]=$title;` so you can : 1st.provide information to user about what it is 2nd. retrieve easily the article when user has followed the link. If you need more information at this moment, you should go with `$data[$dateY][$dateM][$dateD]=$article;` where $article is an Article object.

Comment: What type of data are `$dateY`,`$dateM` and `$dateD`? Can you do a `var_dump($dateY);` before the line 49? and tell me the result.

Comment: Actually, you helped a lot, thanks. (I can't upvote though, too much of a newbie!) The only problem was that I had to typecast the date variables to strings or ints because SimpleXML returns objects which is what causes the illegal offset error. EDIT: Yes, just seen your comment. That was the problem!

Comment: Ok, if this solved your issue, you can close this subject by clicking the check at the left of my answer (+it give me the reputation you wanted to gave).